# Unable to ls in a folder, even as root

Tags: macos, permissions, file-permissions

I'm trying to backup the Mail folder on my Mac, residing at `/Users/{uname}/Library/Mail`

When I `ls -la` the `Library` directory, I see it as:

```
drwx------@   7 {uname}  staff    224 Jan  3 10:55 Mail
```

Now, when I try to `ls -la` *inside* the `Mail` folder, I get this:

```
ls: .: Operation not permitted
```

I tried accessing this folder with my user account `{uname}` but received the same error message. Using `root` didn't help either.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Make sure the folder isn't Locked by running `chflags 0 Mail`
2. Validate that there are no ACLs on the folder using `chmod -a# 0 Mail`. After running this command, I get:

   > chmod: No ACL present 'Mail'
   >
   > chmod: Failed to set ACL on file 'Mail': Operation not permitted

What am I missing here? How am I supposed to back up this folder when I can't even list its contents?

Comment: Why are you using root on a Mac? afaik, ~/Library/Mail isn't a SIP-protected folder, but as you already established your {uname} has full rights, why not use that?

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm unable to access it with my own user either.. `{uname}`

Comment: hmm... quick screen grab of mine - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwpug.jpg - any useful info??

Comment: Mojave has a new privacy protection feature, TCC, that restricts access to ~/Library/Mail (and a number of other locations and OS capabilities). See [this Apple.SE question specifically about Mail](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341959/how-do-programs-access-library-mail-under-osx-10-14-mojave), and [this more general one about TCC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers).

Comment: @GordonDavisson thank you for the pointer! Please submit an answer so I can mark this as resolved. Cheers

Comment: @FloatingRock If there's a way to, I'd rather mark it as a cross-site duplicate. I think it's useful to have a question on this site (as well as Apple.SE), but I don't think it needs a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have to enable Full Disk access for the Terminal app.
It's in the Privacy & Security section of the System Preferences [System Settings from Ventura].